# shell commands in makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake

I'm on linux and I need to create a Makefile with cmake  that modify my makefile in this way:

@old:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.6

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

...stuff
```

@new:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.6

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

       ln -s lib/libfreenect.so.0.0 lib/libfreenect.so

...stuff
```

I need simply to add this command in the makefile but I haven ot idea how to do it..

this is the link to my CMakeLists.txt: http://pastebin.com/YB2kDTr5

Answer (score 2):

You could use `add_custom_command`. Here is an example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_library(mylib SHARED lib.cxx)
add_custom_command(TARGET mylib POST_BUILD COMMAND 
                   "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E create_symlink libmylib.so blah.so)
```